# Program Performance and Efficiency: Multiple print statements vs "\n"

Tags: java, performance

Hi all just a query from an observation I made it might be trivial but I was wondering is there much of a trade off in performance or efficiency in using multiple `System.out.println()` statements as opposed to using one statement and using **"\n"** to create new lines within that statement? Granted for something like printing especially for small programs it may be a non issue but was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`println` will be (marginally) slower, because it writes to standard out once per newline. On the other hand, when you write something like `"\n" + variable + "etc"`, this is actually compiled down to use a `StringBuilder`, which is fairly fast - in any case, faster than writing to standard out.

Of course, you should never use `+"\n"` in place of `println` just for the sake of performance - unless you've measured some sort of performance issue. But in that case, you might want to wrap System.out in a buffer instead.

Answer (score 2):

The expensive part of output is performing the actual output, either to a console or to a file if the output of your process has been re-directed. Writing to a buffer is an inexpensive operation when compared to the actual output.

Even though the output is buffered, each call of `println` will perform the output, because `System.out` is created in autoflush mode. This means that multiple calls of `println` will perform multiple flushes, while a single call with multiple embedded `'\n'` symbols would flush only once. This could give you a slight performance advantage.

However, it is almost certainly a micro-optimization; the only way to find out for sure would be to profile your specific implementation. Readability of your code is much more important, so if embedding `'\n'`s into your strings makes the code more readable, then it's a good thing regardless of the tiny performance implications that it might have.